# Creating a project data source from an entity framework model located in a seperate class project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am having a very hard time trying to find an example of creating a project data source which points to an entity framework model that is located in a separate project. To be more specific I have a simple class project which only contains my entity framework model which I re-use in many projects with no problems.

In a new project I would like to utilize some of the design time data binding facilities of a few commercial data bound controls to speed up some of my development tasks. If I go to add a new project data source, I can only generate a new EF model or add an empty model I cannot add an existing model from a seperate project.

I have tried copying both the connection string and .datasource files from the EF class project but nothing shows up in the "Data Sources" window. I have seen many many articles on how to move the EF model to a seperate class project which works just fine, I just haven't found anything on creating the "design time" project datasource that points to it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: And of course there is a reference to the project of the EF model, is there?

Comment: Yes there is a reference, I have used the EF class project in many projects (in code) with no problems.

Comment: Can you add the data source by doing `Data > Add New Data Source...` in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty dumb about this but I figured out the problem and maybe it will help someone. The project I just happened to be working on is a 64-bit only project. And I'm sure you can guess the rest if any part of the project or any of the assemblies are 64-bit only, anything to do with the datasouces window simple does not work at all. It is a bit annoying there are no errors or logging about it anywhere but what can you do. Thanks everyone who tried to help I appreciate it.